# How to extract all hrefs in a span with class?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the lineups from the spanish liga in 2020/2021 season.
I struggle with getting the player ids and the player names per game and per team.

```
gamedays_url = range(1,39)
url_list = []
daylinks = []
for gameday in gamedays_url:
        url = "https://www.transfermarkt.de/premier-league/spieltag/wettbewerb/ES1/plus/?saison_id=2020&spieltag=" + str(gameday)
        url_list.append(url)
        response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Custom5'})
```

```
homelineup = []

gameLinks = []
for i in range(len(url_list)):
    page = url_list
    tree = requests.get(page[i], headers = {'User-Agent': 'Custom5'})
    soup_2 = BeautifulSoup(tree.content, 'html.parser')
    links_2 = soup_2.find_all("a", {"class": "liveLink"}, href=re.compile("spielbericht"))
    for j in range(len(links_2)):
            gameLinks.append(links_2[j].get("href"))
```

```
for p in range(len(gameLinks)):
    page = gameLinks[p]

    response = requests.get(page, headers={'User-Agent': 'Custom5'})
    lineup_data = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(lineup_data, 'html.parser')

#hometeam information
  homelineup = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "large-6 columns aufstellung-box"})
  for a in homelineup.select('span[class"aufstellung-rueckennummer-name"] a[href]'):
        home_test.append(a.get('href'))
```

But this does not work.

I have a problem by extracting the hrefs within a span that has a class. Moreover I need it for the home and away team.

The span class looks like this:

```
<span class="aufstellung-rueckennummer-name">
    <a href="/dani-parejo/profil/spieler/59561">Parejo</a>                                  
</span>
```

Comment: In your first code block where does the response goes to?

Comment: In your second code block did you made sure the re pattern is correct? In your third code block in your span class you don't have an equal sign for example also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the selectors in this way to select the first team:

```
soup.select('.aufstellung-box .aufstellung-rueckennummer-name a')
```

and to select the sibling container of first team and extract the second one:

```
soup.select('.aufstellung-box + div .aufstellung-rueckennummer-name a')
```

Also avoid these bunch of lists and try to store info in more structure way like `dict` or a single `list` of `dicts`, so you could access and transform  data in an easy way.

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
base_url = 'https://www.transfermarkt.de'
url = 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/spielbericht/index/spielbericht/3431907'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Custom5'}).content)

data = []

for e in soup.select('.aufstellung-box .aufstellung-rueckennummer-name a'):
    data.append({
        'team': e.find_previous('nobr').text,
        'player': e.text,
        'link': base_url+e.get('href')
    })


for e in soup.select('.aufstellung-box + div .aufstellung-rueckennummer-name a'):
        data.append({
        'team': e.find_previous('nobr').text,
        'player': e.text,
        'link': base_url+e.get('href')
    })


data
```

#### Output

```
[{'team': 'SD Eibar', 'player': 'Dmitrović', 'link': 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/marko-dmitrovi%C4%87/profil/spieler/94308'}, {'team': 'SD Eibar', 'player': 'Bigas', 'link': 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/pedro-bigas/profil/spieler/203043'}, {'team': 'SD Eibar', 'player': 'Oliveira', 'link': 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/paulo-oliveira/profil/spieler/139336'}, {'team': 'SD Eibar', 'player': 'Correa', 'link': 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/rober-correa/profil/spieler/223890'}, {'team': 'SD Eibar', 'player': 'Diop', 'link': 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/pape-diop/profil/spieler/39907'}, {'team': 'SD Eibar', 'player': 'Expósito', 'link': 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/edu-exposito/profil/spieler/506248'}, {'team': 'SD Eibar', 'player': 'Álvarez', 'link': 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/sergio-alvarez/profil/spieler/138935'}, {'team': 'SD Eibar', 'player': 'Inui', 'link': 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/takashi-inui/profil/spieler/98249'}, {'team': 'SD Eibar', 'player': 'León', 'link': 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/pedro-leon/profil/spieler/51587'}, {'team': 'SD Eibar', 'player': 'Enrich', 'link': 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/sergi-enrich/profil/spieler/81988'}, {'team': 'SD Eibar', 'player': 'García', 'link': 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/kike-garcia/profil/spieler/93936'}, {'team': 'Celta Vigo', 'player': 'Villar', 'link': 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/ivan-villar/profil/spieler/297194'}, {'team': 'Celta Vigo', 'player': 'Aidoo', 'link': 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/joseph-aidoo/profil/spieler/358250'}, {'team': 'Celta Vigo', 'player': 'Araújo', 'link': 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/nestor-araujo/profil/spieler/64134'}, {'team': 'Celta Vigo', 'player': 'Olaza', 'link': 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/lucas-olaza/profil/spieler/216240'}, {'team': 'Celta Vigo', 'player': 'Mallo', 'link': 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/hugo-mallo/profil/spieler/119905'}, {'team': 'Celta Vigo', 'player': 'Tapia', 'link': 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/renato-tapia/profil/spieler/277137'}, {'team': 'Celta Vigo', 'player': 'Yokuslu', 'link': 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/okay-yokuslu/profil/spieler/137616'}, {'team': 'Celta Vigo', 'player': 'Méndez', 'link': 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/brais-mendez/profil/spieler/309110'}, {'team': 'Celta Vigo', 'player': 'Nolito', 'link': 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/nolito/profil/spieler/70934'}, {'team': 'Celta Vigo', 'player': 'Mor', 'link': 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/emre-mor/profil/spieler/283223'}, {'team': 'Celta Vigo', 'player': 'Aspas', 'link': 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/iago-aspas/profil/spieler/72047'}]
```